# How to view the source code of a library function in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks 10.05 and programming in C , with ffmpeg library . How do I see the source code of a library function ?

**Eg :** I use avformat_open_input(parameters) in my program . I want to see the body of the function . How can I see ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

use a Linux system. then :

1. Type `man 3 <function-name>`
2. The manpage will always tell you which header file has the declaration.